# How can I delete sheet B, but keep the forumula on sheet A that calls sheet B's data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, python

I am creating a python script that will automatically fill in data to excel and export it as a pdf. Every time it runs, it creates and writes to 5 new excel sheets filled with data outputted from a separate piece of software. Think of these sheets as sheets b,c, d, e and f. Sheet A is the one that calls data from these other sheets.

I want the excel workbook to just have Sheet A, but have its cells still have for example '=sheetB!H4'. Then when the python script runs, it will create the sheetb and fill the data which Sheet A can call from. My problem is when I delete these sheets b-f, it also removes the formula in my main sheet, a. Is it possible for me to just have my main sheet, but still have the formulas in Sheet A calling for the other sheets.

Sorry if this is confusing, let me know if you have any questions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If using python, why not have it do calculations and write directly to pdf? I have used/experimented with pisa that changed to xhtml2pdf, weasyprint and maybe others, but not recently, so not sure what is now current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("sheetB!H4")
```

This will keep the sheet reference even if the sheet is deleted.  Then when the new one is placed with the same name it will resolve correctly.

The draw back is that INDIRECT is volatile and will calculate every time Excel changes.  So turn off the Automatic Calcs while you are loading the pages and turn them back on after.

Comment: Perfect! I'll give this a go thank you. Is there a way that I can do this to multiple cells at once or a faster way than going one by one?

Comment: You can write a quick vba routine that goes through the cells and wraps the existing formula in the INDIRECT.

Comment: Where can I look at how to do that? Sorry, i've never used VBA before and only recently started playing with Excel.

Comment: I am sure there are many examples out there.  quick google of `append existing formula vba` should give you a good starting point.